# Obtener contenidos que fueron produicdos hay menos de un tiempo con SQL sobre PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quiero recuperer para los contenidos cual fue producido hay menos de 30 dias :

```
-- veces una personna deu groupo interragi con contenido, 
                SELECT  COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.eclipse_id FROM swipe
          WHERE (swipe.state= 2 OR swipe.state = 3 or swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state =6 or swipe.state=8 or swipe.state=9)
              AND swipe.subscriber_id in %s AND swipe.date >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
            GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id,swipe.eclipse_id
              ORDER BY (swipe.subscriber_id) ASC;
```

Pero me contesto que :

```
I am unable to connect to the database
column "day" does not exist
LINE 4: ....subscriber_id in (306) AND swipe.date >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, ...
                                                             ^

42703
ERROR:  column "day" does not exist
LINE 4: ....subscriber_id in (306) AND swipe.date >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, ...
                                                             ^

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antoine/Swiper/Eclipse-Stats/querySQLPredictions.py", line 82, in request
    (tuple(self.res.iloc[i]['ids']),))
ProgrammingError: column "day" does not exist
LINE 4: ....subscriber_id in (306) AND swipe.date >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, ...
```

Para el ejemplo minimal y verificable aqui esta una tabla `swipe` :

```
subscriber_id eclipse_id date                       state
161           11270      2017-06-07 14:50:07.595999 2
161           10453      2017-06-07 11:27:31.813999 2
156           10453      2017-06-07 11:26:54.319999 1
161           11269      2016-06-07 11:27:39.276000 3
156           10453      2016-06-05 11:00:06.161999 1
156           10453      2016-06-07 11:28:43.901999 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Si me guío por las etiquetas que definiste, el problema sería que estás usando una función de **SQL server** en **Postgres**. Específicamente cuando haces `DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())`, debieras hacer algo así: `CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day'`.

En tu ejemplo sería así: `CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '30 day'`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Entonces, tengo que reemplazar `DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())` con `CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '30 day'` ?

Comment: Ja! Me dice que `ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'1 day'"
LINE 4: ..., 671, 674, 865) AND swipe.date >= CURRENT_DATE + 30 '1 day'`

Comment: Perdón, así:  `CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '30 day'`, exactamente como la habías comentado